# RestKit sync service, advice with temporary objects - How

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I'm making some app and I want to provide offline functionality to it.
Problem is with getting new data from backend as temporary objects not saved in persistent store. Why I want this? Because I want to check whether data from backend is newer than offline one (by update date) If yes then update, otherwise, send it to the backend.

For now I'm trying something like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *apiEmailRequest = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] requestWithObject:@"ApiEmail" method:RKRequestMethodGET path:pathToContent parameters:nil];

RKObjectRequestOperation *apiEmailOperation = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:apiEmailRequest managedObjectContext:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

*********************CHECK FOR BACKEND EMAILS AND OFFLINE ONE ********************** 
NSArray *backendEmails = [mappingResult array];


    for (ApiEmail *backendEmail in backendEmails) {
        if ([backendEmail isKindOfClass:[ApiEmail class]]) {
            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"ApiEmail"];
            NSPredicate *filterByApplication = [NSPredicate
                                                predicateWithFormat:@"emailId == %@", backendEmail.emailId];
            [fetchRequest setPredicate:filterByApplication];

            NSArray *persistentEmails = [[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].persistentStoreManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

            *HERE PUT IT INTO mainQueueManagedObjectContext and 
            saveToPersistentStore else POST it to the backend*    
        }
    }

} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    *ERROR*
}];


return apiEmailOperation;

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] enqueueObjectRequestOperation:apiEmailOperation];
```

Is there any way to do it without creating new RKObjectManager?

Best regards, Adrian.

**UPDATE**

```
-(void)willSave {
[super willSave];
NSDictionary *remoteCommits = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[self committedValuesForKeys:@[@"updateDate"]]];

NSDate *updateDate = [remoteCommits valueForKey:@"updateDate"];

NSComparisonResult result = [self.updateDate compare:updateDate];

if(result == NSOrderedDescending) {
    [self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:self mergeChanges:NO];
} else {
    [self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:self mergeChanges:YES];
}
}
```

After such modification I'm getting *Failed to process pending changes before save.  The context is still dirty after 1000 attempts.*

Comment: Have you looked into KVC validation?

Comment: @Wain man, you're big! Thank you for your suggestion, I think I got it, did one test and worked like charm. I completely forgot about this neat feature... Tomorrow Ill do real-time test and if it'd work, solution appear here. I can't even describe how many times your replies helped me!!

Comment: @Wain unfortunately I'm failing with this... I did in my ApiEmail.m validating but when older data comes from backend everything changes apart from updateDate. Is there way to permit update on entire object? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is unlikely to work in your situation actually, specifically because of the way `discardsInvalidObjectsOnInsert` works.

You may be able to do this by following the below process but additionally implementing `willSave` on the managed object and checking the status there. If you decide to abandon the updates you can try using `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` with a merge flag of `NO`.

---

With KVC validation you have 2 options:

1. edit individual pieces of data as it is imported
2. abandon the import for a whole object

Option 2. requires that you use the Core Data validation to prevent the import. That means doing something like making the date stamp on the object non-optional (i.e. required) and in your KVC validation setting it to nil when you determine that the import should be aborted.

Note that for this to work you need to set `discardsInvalidObjectsOnInsert` on the entity mapping.

Comment: Thanks @Wain for your support. I came to this solution : ApiEmail.m -(BOOL)validateUpdateDate.......... if local date is newer than backend then [self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:self mergeChanges:NO];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil]; return NO;    Is this good solution? What do you think?

Comment: I have to do it with [aObject commitedValuesForKeys] inside willSave method?

Comment: in the KVC validation method I'd wipe the date if it isn't valid. then, in `willSave` check that and wipe the dirty state by refreshing if required

Comment: You shouldn't be using `committedValuesForKeys`, because you need to check the dirty state, not the saved clean state on disk. Also, you should only call `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` if you need to, remove the call where you set the flag to `YES`. The check should be as simple as `self.updateDate == nil`

Answer (score 0):

After big help from @Wain, I finally got it working. Without this brave men I would still be in the sandbox. Solution:

```
-(BOOL)validateUpdateDate:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError {
    NSComparisonResult result = [self.updateDate compare:(NSDate *)*ioValue];

    if (result == NSOrderedDescending) {
        self.updateDate = nil;

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

-(void)willSave {
    [super willSave];

    if (self.updateDate == nil) {

        [self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:self mergeChanges:NO];
    }
}
```

Thank You so much for your time and help.

Best regards, Adrian.